# Angular 7 nested routing with components nested inside modules

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am trying to create a parent-child router using this folder structure approach. First of all, I want to be clear if this folder structure of having components inside modules is fine or should I change anything.

If this looks fine I am having trouble creating nested router which I need to fi. Issue explained below with not working and working example below?

Folder Structure

```
│   app.component.css
│   app.component.html
│   app.component.ts
│   app.module.ts
│   app.routing.ts
│
├───login
│       login.component.css
│       login.component.html
│       login.component.spec.ts
│       login.component.ts
│
└───user                                        //This is a module
    │   user.module.ts
    │   user.routing.ts
    │
    ├───create-user                             //This is a component
    │       create-user.component.css
    │       create-user.component.html
    │       create-user.component.spec.ts
    │       create-user.component.ts
    │
    ├───list-user                               //This is a component
    │       list-user.component.css
    │       list-user.component.html
    │       list-user.component.spec.ts
    │       list-user.component.ts
    │
    └───view-user                               //This is a component
            view-user.component.css
            view-user.component.html
            view-user.component.spec.ts
            view-user.component.ts
```

My app.routing has this

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FullComponent } from './layouts/full/full.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'


export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path:'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
      } 
    ]
  }
];
```

My user.router contains this

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

export const UserRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: CreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: ViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent
  }
];
```

Now when I try to accessing the URL http://localhost:4400/login it works perfectly fine

But when I try the same with http://localhost:4400/admin/user/create my route does not work. I need some help with this.

The following approach is working for me fine I want to follow something like above.

Current Procedure.

app.routing

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FullComponent } from './layouts/full/full.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'


export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path:'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
      } 
    ]
  }
];
```

user.routing

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

export const UserRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create-user',
    component: CreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'view-user',
    component: ViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list-user',
    component: ListComponent
  }
];
```

The following url works fine 
http://localhost:4400/login
http://localhost:4400/create-user

Comment: Your url says `users` but your route has `user` please check

Comment: @Rahul My bad it is user everywhere. I just recreated the name from py project, have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only add hash(#) in app.router `export const appRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' });`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you didn't have your empty path - for in case if you are redirecting to `admim` route your route will be unmatched because the angular routes will search for an empty route in `children` routes since you don't have one it will not match the route

Try something like this

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
      },
      {
        path:''
        component:FullComponent
      } 
    ]
  }
```

Now when you try to navigate to `admin` your `FullCompoment` will be rendered and if you try `/admin/user` it will lazy load your user module

Like same way add an empty path to your `user-routing-module.ts`

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'create',
    pathMatch : 'full'
  }
```

Most probably this will slove your problem - finally make sure that you have imported your routing in the respective modules - hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Grouping closely-related components in a *feature module* is the way to go!

What you are trying to do is called *module lazy loading*. Check the Angular documentation for this topic: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules.

You are missing the declaration of a `UserRoutingModule` inside `user.routing.ts` (I suggest you rename the file to `user-routing.module.ts` to follow the convention). Then you just need to import `UserRoutingModule` in `UserModule` ;)

By the way, once you are using module lazy loading, you should compile/serve your application with the `--aot` (ahead-of-time) flag. You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have imported all modules?

You should import RouterModule.forChild(UserRoutes)in UserRoutingModule,
then, import UserRoutingModule in UserModule

you should verify the correct url

for example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: AppComponent },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
const userRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create', component: CreateUserComponent },
  { path: 'list', component: ListUserComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```